# Update Textbox from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I develop an Window Application with 2 Forms: `Form1` and `Form2`. Both Forms already show on screen.

I have a button in `Form2` call a funtion in `Form1` like:

```
private void btnGetStation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.form.showConnectionStatus();
}
```

`showConnectionStatus` function in `Form1` will call to a function in `Form2` to update information in Textboxes. `configElement` is an string array with 4 elements:

```
public void showConnectionStatus()
{
    Program.form2.updateSMOStatus(configElement[0], configElement[1], configElement[2] + "," + configElement[3]);
}
```

`updateSMOStatus` in `Form2` to update Textboxs value in `Form2`:

```
public void updateSMOStatus(string line, string group, string stationType)
{
      txtLineName.Text = line;
      txtGroupName.Text = group;
      txtStationType.Text = stationType;
}
```

I had debugged and found that all `textbox` value is changed but they not displayed. My question is why value is not display on `Form2`?

and my `Program` class:

```
static class Program
{

     public static Terminal form;
     public static Form2 form2;
     /// <summary>
     /// The main entry point for the application.
     /// </summary>
     [STAThread]
     static void Main()
     {
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          form = new Terminal();
          form2 = new Form2();
          Application.Run(form);
      }
}
```

Comment: BTW! Don't use `group` as variable because it is C# keyword.

Comment: @X-TECH I had found solution by using `delegate`, bro ^^

Comment: @MrNeo: Answers should be submitted as an answer.  The question is not the place for answers.

Comment: @SamAxe: I will change this, bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `delegate` I had solve this problem:

`Form1` add:

```
public delegate void UpdateSMOStatus(string line, string group, string stationType);
public UpdateSMOStatus updateSMOStatus;
```

`showConnectionStatus` function changed to:

```
public void showConnectionStatus()
{
    updateSMOStatus(configElement[0], configElement[1], configElement[2] + "," + configElement[3]);
}
```

`Form2` function would look like:

```
private void btnGetStation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Program.form.updateSMOStatus = new Terminal.UpdateSMOStatus(updateSMOStatus);
     Program.form.showConnectionStatus();

}

public void updateSMOStatus(string line, string group, string stationType)
{
      txtLineName.Text = line;
      txtGroupName.Text = group;
      txtStationType.Text = stationType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update value of Form2 for this you need two changes.
    first one is Close your current form2

```
private void btnGetStation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.form.showConnectionStatus();
    this.Close();

}`
```

Now in form1 make some changes in showConnectionStatus()  method

```
 public void showConnectionStatus()
        {


            Program.form2.updateSMOStatus(configElement[0], configElement[1], configElement[2] + "," + configElement[3]);
            Program.form2.Show();
        }
```

I think it will work fine